# Is there a way to run a command in a script only once, even if the script is run more often?

Tags: bash, shell

So, I'm trying to create a script that ups the brightness of my lamps by a set amount every time I press it.
At the moment, it's simply structured like `get brightness level > add 5%` (simplified).

This works pretty okay, but I tend to press the button very rapidly to get it up to 20% quickly. Because setting the brightness level goes over a json command, this takes between half a second and a second, and I'm waiting to tap for the next level every time, because the script doesn't remember my inputs while it's running.

My idea is to create a script that only raises a variable when the script gets executed, and then after something like 2 seconds, get the variable, calculate the brightness level, and send the command to the lamp.

Now, at the moment, I'm trying to do that with 2 scripts.

One that sets the variable to a .ini file every time it's executed, which is a quick script, so it can keep up with me pressing the button.

Second one that gets executed by the first one, starts of with a sleep action, then gets the variable from the .ini file, and executes the command. This script will get executed a few times, but it should ignore that, because it's still running (sleeping).

What I really want to do, is have all this in one script. In my mind, it could be done like this (ignoring if it can be done in bash at the moment):

- Have a script that gets executed by the first button press, and then keeps active, but registers how many times it 'tries' to get executed, and then acts accordingly.
- Have a script that runs quickly, but only runs the sleep/execute part once in some way, while executing the variable changing part every time.

If anyone knows of a way to do what I'm trying, I'd be happy to try it.

Tim

Comment: The title basically asks for a locking mechanism,while the question meanders into queued event delivery. Maybe you should decide which solution you actually want? Your use case sounds like making the commands faster would be the ultimate fix.

Comment: Well, I don't want a specific solution, except for the best one obviously. I wrote the title a bit quickly, with one solution in mind, and then thought of another. I don't think making the commands faster is an options, at least not the commands that go to the lamps, because it's all wireless, and not much I can improve on that.

Comment: Then maybe - as @tripleee already mentioned -, you could use locking. Since you are asking for a solution on shell level, have a look at the man-page of the `flock` command.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but isn't `flock` mainly used to lock a script, preventing it from being run twice somehow? I'm not sure what I should lock (have absolutely no experience with locking)

Answer (score 1):

You can just play with environment variables to count the number of times the script was called and work accordingly. For example:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    if [ $foovariable -gt 3 ]
    then
            echo yes
    else
            echo no
            foovariable=$((foovariable + 1))
            export foovariable
    fi
```

You only need to set the variable to a given value before call the script:
`export foovariable=1`. Then you will need to call the script using `source` or `.` in order to get the value in the shell with the value that the script is exporting: `source my_script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

So, my personal way to do this (after a lot of tries):

```
# other parts of script

# reference thingy
(
if [[ (Get externally stored variable 'waiting') != 1 ]]; then
    (Store variable 'waiting' externally with value)=1
    sleep 5
    echo "You can run the script as much as you want, this will only show once"
    (Store variable 'waiting' externally with value)=0
fi
) &
```

Short explanation:
The `&` at the end of the parenthesis makes the part of the script in-between the parenthesis run in the background. Basically, when your script reaches the line where it says "reference thingy", it starts the part you've got between the parenthesis in the background, and closes the rest of the script.

The externally stored variable `waiting` is very important. You can not store it locally, since (AFAIK) local variables get deleted when the script ends. Now while the snippet above is running in the background, the variable `waiting` is 1, which prevents the snippet from being run again while it's still running. Simple but effective I'd say.

If you need a way to set and get variables externally, you can try looking at my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34502370/5721694